# Windows 7: Batch file works if located on drive c:, but did not work when located on drive d:. Why?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, access-denied

the batch file contains:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"
```

and i can execute that batch successful if this batch is located an drive c:.

When i copy that batch file to drive d: i always get the error message (in the dosbox):
"Zugriff verweigert" (en: "access denied"). Even if i run the batch as administrator.

User Account Controll (UAC) (de: "Benutzerkontensteuerung") is disabled.

How to run it from drive d successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research:
The installed personal filewall (COMODO Firewall) has a feature called Defense+ which checks local batch executions. Removing the batch from "trusted files" and removeing from "own security rules" brings the popup back to re-decide what is allowed and what is not allowed.

Issue fixed.